# How to begin viewing/handling query results before the execution ends in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query which returns a large result set and it takes over a minute for the query to finish execution.

I was wondering if it is possible to start getting the data partially before the execution ends.

My intention is to handle the data partially in a parallel foreach loop in C#.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You may want to check out the `fast N` query hint

Comment: Make sure you have indexes on your foreign keys. This is usually the single biggest performance enhancement.

Comment: Most likely a hash or sort is blocking the query. Show the query plan https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Answer (score -1):

I think OFFSET & FETCH may be the best option for returning a partial result set: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#using-offset-and-fetch-to-limit-the-rows-returned

However, depending on where the performance constraints are in your T-SQL query, the queries returning part of the result set may not run any faster than the one that returns everything. So you may need to tune your T-SQL queries as well. That said, I don't know if more than a minute is reasonable for your query without seeing it.

Comment: OFFSET/FETCH is unlikely to be any quicker as all previous rows need to be read anyway and if a sort is involved that will still block